# Properly Declaring a Multi-Dimensional Array of Type int in Java

Tags: java

I've looked all around stackoverflow, and have found multiple answers to defining a multiple dimensional array in Java.  Heck I even looked back some of my older code and found similar examples with doubles, but for some reason when utilizing the code out of those examples as well as my own code, I'm getting errors in both Eclipse and IntelliJ like the following:

The following does not give me the above error:

```
public class foo
{
    private int[][] bar()
    {
        int[][] test = new int[10][];
        test[0] = new int[100];
        test[1] = new int[500];
    }  
}
```

The following gives me the above error:

```
public class foo
{
   int[][] test = new int[10][];
   test[0] = new int[100];
   test[1] = new int[500];
}




Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token (for the first line)
Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s) (for the second line)
```

I'm using this to solve problem 28 on Project Euler.

Comment: it compiles fine with my eclipse. Are we missing any code here?

Comment: The problem is most likely in the code before these lines.  Can you show us how you have declared your class which these lines must be in.?

Comment: Have you wrapped this up in a class and a method?

Comment: Please read the stack error carefully. You will find that there is a line number which mostly will direct you to the core problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you placed your code directly in a class. You need to put it inside a method of a class, like this:

```
public class Snippet {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] test = new int[10][];
        test[0] = new int[100];
        test[1] = new int[500];
    }
}
```

Or you could use a static initializer:

```
public class Snippet {
    static int[][] test = new int[10][];
    static {
        test[0] = new int[100];
        test[1] = new int[500];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hah, I'm not that much of a spring chicken.  I simply removed the rest of the code for brevity.  Thank you for your response and thoroughness though.

Comment: @arete in your question you have statements directly in the class body which is not allowed. You need to move the test[0], test[1] statements into methods, constructors or initializers

Comment: So why is it that this is necessary?

Answer (score 0):

If it says '{' expected, your mistake is in the lines before this.

Answer (score 0):

try these declarations.. I don't know if I got ur point.

```
int[][] test = new int[][]{
 { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
 { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
 { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
 };
 //change zeroes with your values
```

or

```
int[][] test= new int[3][10];
```